# Efficient way to check file types and organizing final String's (Java)

Tags: java, file, oop

I'm writing a program that allows exporting columns from a database table to a workbook. Now, the user may choose different kinds of database files. So far, I only have an Access driver Connection that allows to connect to an Access file:

```
private final String ACCESS_DRIVER_CONN = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"; //class variable
```

I have this method in the same class:

```
public Connection createConnection() throws IOException {
    Connection result = null;
    DatabaseFileUtility dbUtil = new DatabaseFileUtility();
    String dbFileLoc = "";  // is the location of database selected
    String fileType = "";       

    while(!dbUtil.isValidFile(fileType) && dbFileLoc != null) {
        dbFileLoc = dbUtil.getFileLocation();
        if(dbFileLoc != null) {
            fileType = dbUtil.getFileExtension(dbFileLoc);
        }
    }

    if(dbFileLoc != null) {
        try {
            if(fileType.equalsIgnoreCase(FileExtensions.ACCDB)) {
                result = DriverManager.getConnection(ACCESS_DRIVER_CONN + dbFileLoc);
            }

            // add more DB file types here
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Instead of doing this, my manager asked me if I can write all the strings containing the connection drivers in a text file. But I use the FileExtensions class that I made to determine what kind of file the user is trying to open. This is the FileExtensions class:

```
public abstract class FileExtensions {
    public static final String ACCDB = "accdb";
    public static final String XLS = "xls";
}
```

I also use the FileExtensions in my DatabaseFileUtility class, to determine if the file they are opening is valid:

```
public boolean isValidFile(String fileType) {
    boolean result = false;

    if(fileType instanceof String) {
        switch(fileType) {
            case FileExtensions.ACCDB: result = true;
                break;

            // insert more cases/db-file-extensions here

            default: result = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the same method in my ExcelFileUtility class, except the cases should only contain Excel files to return true.

I know this is **not** the most efficient way of doing this. But this is my first time writing a program this big on my own and I don't exactly know how to organize yet. My manager asked me if I can write the Strings that are final in a text file instead, and I understand that this will make it easier for non-programmers to add more connections. But since I use the FileExtensions for checking, and they are also final variables, should I make a separate text files for the extensions as well? Actually, is doing this kind of (file extension) checking efficient at all? Is there an easier and more organized and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Putting locations etc in a text or configuration file is usually not a bad thing as it separates configuration from logic. I would recommend to use XML files or something similar instead of plain text files to make it more universal and easily parseable by most programming languages.

Comment: You can then write a class that reads out the configuration once and store it for other classes to access. This way you don't have to parse text files every time you need to access the configuration.

Comment: @brimborium Ok, I did some research about how to write/use XML, and actually coded with it. But my problem is that I want non-programmers to be able to change things around, like if they want to add more connections or extensions.

Comment: That is certainly possible with XML. Just let them use an XML editor that is not showing the XML code directly. There are a bunch of those around. I just think its better to use one of those formats instead of a custom text format that you then have to parse by yourself. The text format is much more vulnerable because it is implemented by one person (you) instead of a whole community over years.